# Add additional information to request

Tags: python, django, django-views

I have an e-commerce website I'm working on, and I'd like it to be able to do something like this:

```
class Shop(ListView):
    # Set the model as Product, the rest is handled by Django
    model = Product
    # Name of HTML File to show
    template_name = 'store/shop.html'
    # What to refer to in the HTML file (injection)
    context_object_name = 'products'

    # If the request.method is POST (a filter request)
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # Function from utils.py
        min_price, max_price, products = filter_shop(request)
        print(min_price, max_price)

        # Function from utils.py
        data = cartData(self.request)
        # Assigning keys to keys in context which can then be referenced in the html
        # Pass is in the completed query as a option, plus cartitems for the cart
        context_dict = {'products': products, 'cartitems': data['cartItems'], 'min_price': min_price,
                        'max_price': max_price, 'categories': category_choices()}
        return render(request, 'store/shop.html', context_dict)

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        category = self.kwargs['category']
        if category == 'custom':
            return super().get(request, *args, **kwargs)
        elif category == 'men':
            context_dict = {'men-coats': 'on'}

            request = request + context_dict
            return self.post(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

What's happening is that the get request looks for something in the URL, and then needs to run the request as if it is a post request, I just need to add some post data into that request before I send it off, as you can see I tried to do with the context_dict, this did not work and it is why I am asking for help, the main thing to look at is the elif inside the post request. Thank you.

Comment: What does `return self.post(request, *args, **kwargs)` do?

Comment: It's just a filtering system, I didn't post that because I don't think it's relevant to the question, the "men-coats" option is just an option when you do a post request, part of the form, I'm trying to replicate that form